# Homemade Lightbox and Image Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to JavaScript, and I've built a lightbox for an image gallery. There's a button to open the gallery, plus forwards, backwards, and close buttons, and keyboard controls. Currently, everything works exactly the way I intended, but I know that it can be more DRY, and would love some feedback on that.

Here is the relevant HTML for the image container:

```
<div class="gallery" data-image-source="img/gallery/project_main/1_IntegratedFarming.jpg">
    <button class="secondary">
        <i class="icon-gallery"></i>
        <span>View Gallery</span>
    </button>            
</div>
```

And this is the JavaScript:

```
var fillGalleryContainers = function() {
    $(".gallery").each(function(){
        $(this).css("background-image", "url('" + $(this).attr("data-image-source") + "')");
    });
};

var generateLightbox = function() {
    var $lightboxOverlayHTML = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
    var $lightboxImageActiveHTML = $('<img class="gallery-image--active">');
    var $lightboxImageNextHTML = $('<img class="gallery-image--next">');
    var $logoPCLHTML = $('<i class="icon-pcl" id="logoPCL"></i>');
    var $logoCommunityHTML = $('<i class="icon-community-alt" id="logoCommunity"></i>');
    var $closeGalleryHTML = $('<i class="icon-close" id="closeGallery"></i>');
    var $navNextHTML = $('<i class="icon-arrow-right" id="navNext"></i>');
    var $navPrevHTML = $('<i class="icon-arrow-left" id="navPrev"></i>');

    $lightboxOverlayHTML.append(
        $lightboxImageActiveHTML,
        $lightboxImageNextHTML,
        $logoPCLHTML,
        $logoCommunityHTML,
        $navPrevHTML,
        $navNextHTML,
        $closeGalleryHTML
    );

    $('body').append($lightboxOverlayHTML);
};

var openLightbox = function() {
    $('.gallery button').click(function(event){

        var imageSource = $(this).parent().css("background-image");
        var $lightboxOverlay = $('#overlay');
        var $lightboxImageActive = $('.gallery-image--active');
        var $lightboxImageNext = $('.gallery-image--next');
        window.currentOverflow = $("html").css("overflow");

        imageSource = imageSource.replace('url(', '').replace(')','');
        $lightboxImageActive.attr("src", imageSource);

        $lightboxOverlay.css({
            top: $(window).scrollTop(),
            left: $(window).scrollLeft()
        });

        $lightboxOverlay.fadeIn(1000);
        $('html').css("overflow", "hidden");

    });
};

var closeLightBox = function() {
    $('#overlay').fadeOut(1000);
    $("html").css("overflow", window.currentOverflow);
};

var galleryNavigationNext = function() {
    var $activeImage = $('.gallery-image--active');
    var $nextImage = $('.gallery-image--next');

    var galleryImages = window.galleryImages;
    var galleryTotal = galleryImages.length;

    var location = window.location.href;
    var currentImageSource = $activeImage.attr('src');
    var modImageSource = currentImageSource.replace(location, '');

    var currentPosition = $.inArray(modImageSource, galleryImages);
    if (currentPosition < 0 ) {
        currentPosition = 0;
    }

    var next = (currentPosition + 1 < galleryImages.length - 1) ? currentPosition + 1 : 0;

    $nextImage.attr('src', galleryImages[next]);

    $activeImage.fadeOut(1000, function() {

        $activeImage.removeClass('gallery-image--active').addClass('remove');
        $nextImage.addClass('gallery-image--active').removeClass('gallery-image--next');
        $('.remove').remove();
        $('.gallery-image--active').after('<img class="gallery-image--next">');
    });
};

var galleryNavigationPrev = function() {
    var $activeImage = $('.gallery-image--active');
    var $nextImage = $('.gallery-image--next');

    var galleryImages = window.galleryImages;
    var galleryTotal = galleryImages.length;

    var location = window.location.href;
    var currentImageSource = $activeImage.attr('src');
    var modImageSource = currentImageSource.replace(location, '');

    var currentPosition = $.inArray(modImageSource, galleryImages);
    if (currentPosition < 0 ) {
        currentPosition = 0;
    }

    var next = (currentPosition - 1 >= 0) ? currentPosition - 1 : galleryImages.length - 1;

    $nextImage.attr('src', galleryImages[next]);

    $activeImage.fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $activeImage.removeClass('gallery-image--active').addClass('remove');
        $nextImage.addClass('gallery-image--active').removeClass('gallery-image--next');
        $('.remove').remove();
        $('.gallery-image--active').after('<img class="gallery-image--next">');
    });
};

var galleryEvents = function() {

    // Close Events
    $('#closeGallery').click(closeLightBox);
    $(document.documentElement).keyup(function(e){
        if (event.keyCode == 88 || event.keyCode == 27) {
            closeLightBox();
        }
    });

    // Open Events

    // Previous Events
    $('#navPrev').click(galleryNavigationPrev);
    $(document.documentElement).keyup(function(e){
        if (event.keyCode == 37) {
            galleryNavigationPrev();
        }
    });

    //  Next Events 
    $('#navNext').click(galleryNavigationNext);
    $(document.documentElement).keyup(function(e){
        if (event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 32) {
            galleryNavigationNext();
        }
    });

};
```

Here is how the `galleryImages` array gets populated (which will be populated via Wordpress). It's just an inline script at the bottom of the page.

```
<script>
    window.galleryImages = [
        "img/gallery/project_main/1_IntegratedFarming.jpg",
        "img/gallery/project_main/2_BuildaCity.jpg",
        "img/gallery/project_main/3_LearningCenter.jpg",
        "img/gallery/project_main/4_CommonGrounds.jpg",
        "img/gallery/project_main/project_main_gallery01.jpg",
        "img/gallery/project_main/project_main_gallery02.jpg",
        "img/gallery/project_main/project_main_gallery03.jpg",
        "img/gallery/project_main/project_main_gallery04.jpg",
        "img/gallery/project_main/project_main_gallery05.jpg",
        "img/gallery/project_main/project_main_gallery06.jpg",
        "img/gallery/project_main/project_main_gallery07.jpg",
        "img/gallery/project_main/project_main_gallery08.jpg",
        "img/gallery/project_main/project_main_gallery09.jpg",
    ];
</script>
```

I know that the `galleryNavigationNext` and previous functions can be combined, but I'm not quite sure how passing variables from functional calls works. I've tried the below and it didn't work:

```
var galleryNavigation = function(direction) {
    var $activeImage = $('.gallery-image--active');
    var $nextImage = $('.gallery-image--next');

    var galleryImages = window.galleryImages;
    var galleryTotal = galleryImages.length;

    var location = window.location.href;
    var currentImageSource = $activeImage.attr('src');
    var modImageSource = currentImageSource.replace(location, '');

    var currentPosition = $.inArray(modImageSource, galleryImages);
    if (currentPosition < 0 ) {
        currentPosition = 0;
    }

    var next;

    if (direction === "next") {
        next = (currentPosition + 1 < galleryImages.length - 1) ? currentPosition + 1 : 0;
    } else if (direction === "prev") {
        next = (currentPosition - 1 >= 0) ? currentPosition - 1 : galleryImages.length - 1;
    }

    $nextImage.attr('src', galleryImages[next]);

    $activeImage.fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $activeImage.removeClass('gallery-image--active').addClass('remove');
        $nextImage.addClass('gallery-image--active').removeClass('gallery-image--next');
        $('.remove').remove();
        $('.gallery-image--active').after('<img class="gallery-image--next">');
    });
};

var galleryEvents = function() {

    $('#navPrev').click(galleryNavigation("prev"));
    $(document.documentElement).keyup(function(e){
        if (event.keyCode == 37) {
            galleryNavigation("prev");
        }
    });

    $('#navNext').click(galleryNavigation("next"));
    $(document.documentElement).keyup(function(e){
        if (event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 32) {
            galleryNavigation("next");
        }
    });

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be reviewing your first chunk of code.

**`fillGalleryContainers`**

- In the future, you'll probably<sup>†</sup> be able to just write:

  ```
  $(".gallery").css("background-image", "url(attr(data-image-source url))");
  ```
- For now, instead of `.attr("data-image-source")`, you can use `.data("image-source")`.
- You may want to save your `$(this)` object into a variable. Creating jQuery objects is not free.

**`generateLightbox`**

- This is cute, but I'm not sure that there's really any value in creating a jQuery object for each line of HTML; it's definitely less performant than just mashing it all into one string.

  ```
  $lightboxOverlay =
      $('<div id="overlay">' +
        '    <img class="gallery-image--active" />' +
          [...]
        '</div>');
  ```

  The rest of the points are independent of this one.
- It doesn't make much sense to me to name the variables `$...HTML`. It doesn't actually represent the HTML (that would be just the string); instead, it's a jQuery object, which is made clear by the `$` prefix. I'd prefer, e.g. `var $navPrev = ...;`.
- I *really* do not like the use of `<i>` here. This is semantic garbage, to be blunt. You could be using `<button>` or `<a>`, or even `<img>`, but using `<i>` is bad.
- As a matter of taste, you could choose to use `$lightboxOverlay.appendTo('body');` instead of `$('body').append($lightboxOverlay);`. This would allow you to just chain the method on.

**`openLightbox`**

- This is the first function where you've been inconsistent in quotes. I can't really tell if you prefer `"` or `'`, but you should stick with one or the other. You can make exceptions for when the string will contain a lot of the same type of quote; for example, I like all my strings to use double-quotes, but when I'm writing a string with HTML, I use single-quotes, like you did in `generateLightbox`.
- Prefer `.on('click', function...` over `.click(function...`.
- You aren't using `event`, so no need to put it in. Just go with `function() {...`.
- `$lightboxActiveImage` and `$lightboxNextImage` sound a bit better to me, but it's a matter of taste.
- In fact, you don't even use `$lightboxImageNext`, so just get rid of it.
- I would prefer the following, in case your `background-image` `url` for some reason has `)` in it. It reads more cleanly to me too, but that might just be me.

  ```
  imageSource = imageSource.match(/^url\('(.+)'\)$/)[1];
  ```
- I notice that you're storing the current value of `overflow` on your `<html>` element. This isn't strictly necessary: unless the `<html>` tag actually has a `style='overflow: scroll;'` on it, you can just set it to empty string later:

  ```
  $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
  // later, in closeLightbox
  $("html").css("overflow", "");
  ```
- Take advantage of method chaining: `$lightboxOverlay.css().fadeIn();`.
- If you can deal with `openLightbox` always resetting, then instead of using `imageSource`, you could just do:

  ```
  $lightboxImageActive.attr("src", $(this).parent().data("image-source"));
  ```
- Frankly, I don't like that the `openLightbox` function actually just assigns an event handler. I'd rather do that in the `galleryEvents` function.

**`closeLightBox`**

- No. Bad. This name is inconsistent with the rest of your code. Rename it to `closeLightbox`.
- As stated before, just do `$("html").css("overflow", "");`.

**`galleryNavigationNext`** and **`galleryNavigationPrev`**

You're right; these two functions share a lot of code. I propose a single function, which I'll call `galleryNavigateRelative`. I'll add that to the end of this section, but first, the line-by-line analysis:

- You never use `galleryTotal`. Take it out.
- I notice that you try to "unresolve" the image `src`. I think a better solution would be to resolve and normalise `window.galleryImages` when loading. If you use the [URI.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) library, you can resolve like so:

  ```
  window.galleryImages = window.galleryImages.map(function(val) { return URI(val).absoluteTo().toString(); });
  ```

  This will also deal with any pesky accidental `//`s. (A note of caution: if your string *starts* with `//`, then this will not behave quite as you expect.)
- The assignment of `currentPosition` could be simplified:

  ```
  var currentPosition = Math.max(0, $.inArray(modImageSource, galleryImages));
  ```
- Your calculation of `next` seems like a perfect use case for the modulus operator `%`:

  ```
  var next = (currentPosition + 1) % galleryImages.length;
  ```
- The logic in the callback for `fadeOut` is pretty complicated and could be simplified. You're immediately removing `$activeImage`, so why bother with the classes? Also, why do a new search for `.gallery-image--active` when you already have it as `$nextImage`?

  ```
  $activeImage.fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $activeImage.remove();
      $nextImage.toggleClass("gallery-image--active gallery-image--next")
                .after('<img class="gallery-image--next" />');
  });
  ```
- Here's what you'll need to change to DRY it up:

  ```
  var galleryNavigateRelative = function(delta) {
      ...
      var next = (currentPosition + delta) % galleryImages.length;
      ...
  }
  ```

**`galleryEvents`**

- I don't like the function name. Change it to something like `bindGalleryEvents` or `galleryBindEvents`, if you want to stick with the pseudo-namespacing. You need a verb of some sort in there.
- Again, prefer `.on("click", ...` and `.on("keyup", ...`.
- In your case, there's no difference<sup>‡</sup> between assigning a `keyup` handler to `$(document)`, so use that for brevity.
- jQuery normalises `event.which`, so use that over `.keyCode`. (I think `.keyCode` might work too, but I believe it's typical practice to use `which`.)
- If you're passing `e` to your callback, then why use the global `event` in the body?
- You may wish to aggregate your `keyup` handlers.
- In your `keyup` handlers, consider commenting what the `keyCode` represents.
- As mentioned before, it's better to bind the `openLightbox` function here.
- With our `galleryNavigateRelative` function, we'll need to do something slightly different when binding to `#navPrev` and `#navNext`:

  ```
  $("#navPrev").on("click", function() { galleryNavigateRelative(-1); });
  // and similar for next
  ```

Here's my final reviewed version of your code:

```
var fillGalleryContainers = function() {
    $(".gallery").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css("background-image", "url('" + $this.data("image-source") + "')");
    });
};

var generateLightbox = function() {
    $("body").append(
        '<div id="overlay">' +
        '    <img class="gallery-image--active" />' +
        '    <img class="gallery-image--next" />' +
        '    <a class="icon-pcl" id="logoPCL"></a>' +
        '    <button class="icon-community-alt" id="logoCommunity"></button>' +
        '    <button class="icon-close" id="closeGallery"></button>' +
        '    <button class="icon-arrow-right" id="navNext"></button>' +
        '    <button class="icon-arrow-left" id="navPrev"></button>' +
        '</div>'
    );
};

var openLightbox = function() {
    // `this' is a `.gallery button'
    var $lightboxOverlay = $("#overlay");
    var $lightboxActiveImage = $(".gallery-image--active");

    $lightboxImageActive.attr("src", $(this).parent().data("image-source"));

    $lightboxOverlay.css({
        top: $(window).scrollTop(),
        left: $(window).scrollLeft()
    }).fadeIn(1000);

    $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
};

var closeLightbox = function() {
    $("#overlay").fadeOut(1000);
    $("html").css("overflow", "");
};

var galleryNavigateRelative = function(delta) {
    var $activeImage = $(".gallery-image--active");
    var $nextImage = $(".gallery-image--next");

    var galleryImages = window.galleryImages;

    var location = window.location.href;
    var currentImageSource = $activeImage.attr("src");
    var modImageSource = currentImageSource.replace(location, "");

    var currentPosition = $.inArray(modImageSource, galleryImages);
    if (currentPosition < 0 ) {
        currentPosition = 0;
    }

    var next = (currentPosition + delta) % galleryImages.length;

    $nextImage.attr("src", galleryImages[next]);

    $activeImage.fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $activeImage.remove();
        $nextImage.toggleClass("gallery-image--active gallery-image--next")
                  .after('<img class="gallery-image--next" />');
    });
};

var galleryEvents = function() {
    // open/close
    $("#closeGallery").on("click", closeLightbox);
    $(".gallery button").on("click", openLightbox);

    // navigation
    $("#navPrev").click(function() {
        galleryNavigateRelative(-1);
    });
    $("#navNext").click(function() {
        galleryNavigateRelative(+1);
    });

    // keyboard handling
    $(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
        if (e.which == 88 || e.which == 27) {
            // "x" or ESC
            closeLightbox();
        } else if (e.which == 37) {
            // left arrow
            galleryNavigateRelative(-1);
        } else if (e.which == 39 || e.which == 32) {
            // right arrow or space
            galleryNavigateRelative(+1);
        }
    });
};
```

---

<sup><sup>†</sup> I say "probably" because although it's a CSS3 Candidate Recommendation, it's considered at-risk due to poor browser support.

<sup>‡</sup> Strictly, your code will be assigning the `keyup` handler to `$("html")`, but they'll do the same thing.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. You really did a thorough job, and its all very relevant. Thanks! One follow up question, I've asked around a bit and haven't gotten a great answer yet, but is there a reason that on.('click') is preferred over click('')? Same goes for any event, really. Thanks!

Comment: @idealbrandon I guess it doesn't really matter. `.click()` is the shorthand. [It adds a very, very slight overhead (a conditional check and an additional function call)](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event/alias.js#L13), but this is negligible. I've always used `.on` out of habit because of how versatile it is (if you want to handle multiple events, you can do `.on("click mouseleave", ...)` or something) and because it allows me to easily convert an event binding to a delegated event (`.on("click", ".added-by-ajax", ...)`).